# Scroll to next or previous element with buttons and fixed navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, anchor-scroll

I've successfully implemented [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/6r1h687k/) on my bootstrap 4 project, but I need to add a -60px offset top in order to match a static and fixed top navbar. I've added the value (-60) for both "next" and "previous" buttons this way:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({ 
              scrollTop: $scrollItems.eq(pagePositon).offset().top -60
        }, 300);
```

but after doing it, I have to click twice on the "next" button in order to perform the action, and the "previous" button does not reach the first section: [look the result here](http://jsfiddle.net/franbagg/o4ux5m26/10).

Any advice on how to do add those -60px offset top in this case?? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question but for button next you can put 120 instead 60, no? Obsviously you would have to test if its the first click or not, since the first click works fine.

Comment: The problem is in function upPos

Comment: If you comment on this line the problem disappears `$(window).bind('scroll ' ,upPos)`

Comment: An alternative to continue using this function without these problems is to change this line: `if ($(ele).offset().top < fromTop + offsetTolorence)`, change to `if ($(ele).offset().top - 60 < fromTop + offsetTolorence)`

Comment: AksJacoves, line commented and problems solved! Thank you so much for your help.